# Failed password from invalid user accepted?

Tags: ssh

Today I’ve received this notification from Papertrail. I’ve set up my logs to send notifications every time a successful login happens.

```
Dec 11 10:29:00 akira sshd: Failed password for invalid user accepted from 178.207.160.6 port 39614 ssh2
```

I can’t wrap my head around it.

How is it possible for a failed password, from an invalid user to be accepted?

Comment: That's “Failed password for invalid user ‘accepted’ from ...”. That is, the remote system sent the user name `accepted` and a password; the server is logging that the user name `accepted` is invalid. Try to log in with another user name and look at the logs.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you are saying but I get hundreds of attempts and I none get past my filters to notify me. This one did.

Comment: That depends on the specific filters, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, I’ve checked my filter and it’s set to notify me every time the word Accepted and password appears in the sshd logs. That’s one clever attacker. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://blackhat.directory/ip/178.204.213.175   It seems from russia.

Answer (score -4):

This is a generic failure log message. For me, the root cause was:

```
Dec  6 10:40:21 lldevgt-icormac sshd[29417]: User sftp_user from 127.0.0.1 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
```

To fix, I added `sftp_user` to the list of AllowedUsers in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
AllowUsers sftp_user [other_users]
```

Then restarted ssh:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1267152)